# How can I parse XML data using Visual Basic

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have XML data like this:

```
<search ver="3.0">
  <loc>Birmingham, AL</loc> 
  <loc>Gulf Shores, AL</loc> 
  <loc>Alabama, NY</loc> 
  <loc>Abbeville, AL</loc> 
  <loc>Abernant, AL</loc> 
</search>
```

I would like to return the name of the places. How may I extract this data using Visual Basic?

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Don't roll it back, please.

Comment: @John W - it's there, but the OP keeps overwriting the edits that people have provided to show the XML formatted properly

Comment: I keep adding the xml code but it wont display?it only display the innerhtml

Comment: how did you do that by the way?

Comment: @hubby - to format code, the easiest way is to highlight the code and click the "101|010" button in the markdown editor... all it does it indent your text 4 spaces which will be rendered as code. It's not easy to find (well yet, at least: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001306.html), but you can find more details on the full syntax here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you don't do this in your XML, but maybe you have a good reason:

```
<loc>
    <city>Birmingham</city>
    <state>AL</state>
</loc>
```

But anyway, if you get the loc elements in your original XML, you can use the [Split method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28VS.80%29.aspx) to pull it apart.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
public function returnstring()as string() 
Dim suggestions As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
Dim baseUrl As String = "path to my xml file"
settings.IgnoreWhitespace = True
settings.IgnoreComments = True
```

Using reader As XmlReader = XmlReader.Create(url, settings)
                While (reader.Read())
                    If (reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element And reader.LocalName = "loc" ) Then

```
                    suggestions.Add(reader.ReadElementString("loc"))

                End If
            End While
```

End Using
return suggestions.toarray()

end function

Answer (score 0):

//  Easy way:

```
Dim docxml As New DOMDocument30
Dim element As IXMLDOMElement

Dim Node As IXMLDOMNode

docxml.Load app.path & "configiw.xml"
text1.text = docxml.getElementsByTagName("loc").Item(0).Text 
'Zero is the number of the line, you can use a while or a for
```